# Как работает Using в запросах SQL?

Tags: sql

У нас есть запрос:

```
SELECT title, year, p.name AS pub, a.name AS author 
FROM book 
JOIN publisher AS p USING (publisher_id) 
JOIN book_author USING (book_id)
JOIN author AS a USING (author_id) 
WHERE a.author_id=1 
ORDER BY year
```

В первом случае `Using` соединяет по `publisher_id` таблицы `book` и `publisher`.

Во втором случае `Using` соединяет по `book_id` таблицы `book` и `book_author`.

В третьем случае соединяет по `author_id` уже `book_author` и `author`

Я же правильно понимаю, что `JOIN` всегда соединяет с уже целой соединенной таблицей как бы которая образовалась из всех соединений слева,
т.е. исходная таблица - Первый `JOIN` соединяет с исходной - Второй `JOIN`
соединяет уже с объединенной исходной и той что получилась от первого `JOIN`'a и т.д. ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как `using` понимает какие таблицы соединять? А если во всех трёх таблицах будет поле с `author_id`?

Comment: `using(columnName)` - это сокращённая запись `ON table1.columnName = table2.columnName` вот и вся хитрость

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: (дополнительно) При использовании USING в итоговом списке вывода при использовании `SELECT *` будет одно поле `columnName`, а не два, причём в начале списка вывода. Также на это поле можно ссылаться без алиаса таблицы во WHERE и GROUP BY (при этом будет использоваться значение левой таблицы при INNER/LEFT JOIN и правой - при RIGHT JOIN). С обеих сторон связывания имя поля должно быть уникально (см. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a07154ff7a1cd2002cdf72973dd38c05)

Comment: @Akina ответы - в ответы. :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не я начал (в смысле - не я первым дал ответ) - не мне и писать как ответ.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский то что это сокращенная запись по ON это понятно но в моём примере using применяется то к таблице 1 и 2 то к таблице 1 и 3 то к  2 и 3 в этом собственно и вопрос как using определяет с какой таблицей соединять

Comment: Как я сказал - во-первых, поля должны иметь оба заданное имя, во, вторых, не должно быть неопределённостей. А что слева две-три таблицы - это ни на что не влияет, лишь бы среди них поле с таким именем было бы единственным. Ссылочку-то посмотрите...

Comment: @Akina понял спасибо больше! Ссылку не увидел сначала!

Comment: @Qwertiy  ↑↑↑ Там лучше ответ и развёрнутый, но он нихатит писать)